# Easier way to query an XML file? C# - MVC .Net

Tags: c#, xml

As of now, my code is working perfectly and there are no issues but I wanted input on if there's an easier way to reading XML files.

So here's a summary on what I'm doing:

1. I have a large program that deals with several outside factors. At one point, I am given an XML file
   that has many different elements and child nodes.
2. For each anticipated element, I created a class that has variables which will hold all the data from
   the node.

This isn't what my XML file looks like but here is a simple example mocking it so you have a better idea what I'm working with.

```
   -<status>
   -<CallBase FilePath="EU\Domain Users" CallValid="True" CodedPath="D:\Users\CASE\" 
   TracePath="D:\Users\CASE\" StartEnviorment="" ServerLogs="" ServerPath="" ConfigPort="217757" 
   PacePort="217757" Version="2.5.0.73" Version2="10.3.0.73" VersionName="CASEservice" 
   LastTimeCheck="08/05/2020 15:05:07">
   <ValidPermissions Default=""/>
   </CallBase>
   </status>
```

I created a class for the CallBase element called "CallBase" that contains strings for FilePath, CallValid,CodedPath, TracePath, StartEnviorment, ServerLogs, ServerPath, ConfigPort, PacePort, Version and so on.

Here's how I'm reading this specific node and storing it in a CallBase object:

```
private CallBase getCallBaseData(List<XmlDocument> xmlDoc, int i)                                             
    {
        var result = xmlDoc[i].DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//CallBase");
        foreach (var node in result)
        {
            var temp1 = node.ToString();
        }

        XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDoc[i].SelectSingleNode("//CallBase");

        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CallBase));

        CallBase tempresult = (CallBase)serial.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(xmlNode));

        return tempresult;
    }
```

However, now I have a ton of the same functions and I replace the "CallBase" with a different element name. I'm wondering if there's a different way to do this so I only have one function.

Comment: `if there's an easier way to reading XML files`, sure there is, there's always ways to improve code. My suggestion since you're not having any issues, is head over to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and create a post there.

Comment: There are lots of method for passing xml in c#.  The best method varies depending on a number of factors 1) Have schema or classes 2) Speed 3) Size of file 4) Amount of data needed 5) structure of xml file 6) Format of output needed.  I usually use one of 3 methods 1) Xml Linq 2) Xml Serialize 3) XmlReader (or combination of the 3).

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Oh sorry I didn't know that existed till just now! Thank you :)

Comment: @jdweng Right, I understand. I'm new to querying XML so I think my way was a bit redundant but working on improving my skills

Comment: Not really.  If the classes you create don't start a root of xml you have to move to the element that matches you root class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set of methods that differ only in the type of elements can be replaced with one [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods).

Fortunately, the name of the xml element matches the name of the class type. We'll get it from there with [Type.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.name?view=netstandard-1.6&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1) property.

```
private T GetData<T>(List<XmlDocument> xmlDoc, int i)
{
    var xpath = "//" + typeof(T).Name;

    var result = xmlDoc[i].DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath);

    foreach (var node in result)
    {
        var temp1 = node.ToString();
    }

    var xmlNode = xmlDoc[i].SelectSingleNode(xpath);

    var serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    var tempresult = (T)serial.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(xmlNode));

    return tempresult;
}
```

Using:

```
GetData<CallBase>(..., ...);
```

Comment: You are awesome! I tried doing something similar and it wouldn't work, thanks :)

Comment: Alexander, can you add an introductory paragraph to this, to help future readers? We tend to find that answers are more useful if they can be explained.